# Related Rates problem boat

Tags: calculus

A boat is pulled in to a dock by a rope with one end attached to the front of the boat and the other end passing through a ring attached to the dock at a point $\sqrt{275}$ ft higher than the front of the boat. The rope is being pulled through the ring at the rate of $0.2$ ft/sec. How fast is the boat approaching the dock when 18 ft of rope are out?

I have run through this problem, I found the $x$ value was $\sqrt{18^2-275}$ or $7$ and that $z$ was $18$ and the change in $z$ is $.2$ so I plugged it all in and got $(\frac {18}{7})*.2$ but it says that is wrong.  I don't know what I am missing I have done it a couple times can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be the distance to the dock and $r$ be the length of the rope.  Then you have 
$$d^2 + 275 = r^2.$$
At the instance of interest you have $r = 18$ and $r' = -.2$, where ' 
means time derivative.  Using our relationship we have $324 = d^2 + 275$
so $d = 7$.  Now take the time derivative on the pythagorean relationship.
$$2dd' = 2rr'.$$
Dropping in the stuff we know we have
$$2\cdot 7 \cdot d' = 2\cdot 18 \cdot (-.2),$$
so $d' = -3.6/7 = -.514 \rm{ft}/\rm{sec}$.
Note that the negative tells us the boat is drawing nearer to the dock.
Your answer looks pretty good, but the nuance about the negative is important.

Comment: I tried the same thing, it didn't work, I tried both positive and negative and fraction form and decimal. I can't figure out what its wrong

Answer (score 0):

If $l$ is the length of the rope and $s$ is the distance from the boat to the dock, then you can draw a right triangle and see that
\begin{equation} l^2 = 275 + s^2 \end{equation}
Differentiating both sides by $t$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \left[ l^2 \right] &= \frac{d}{dt} \left[275 + s^2 \right] \\
2l \frac{dl}{dt} &= 2s \frac{ds}{dt} \\
l \frac{dl}{dt} &= s \frac{ds}{dt}
\end{align}

We are given that $\frac{dl}{dt} = -0.2 \text{ ft/s}$ (since $l$ is decreasing) and that $l = 18 \text{ ft}$. Using the first equation, we see that $s = 7 \text{ ft}$, and so
\begin{align}
l \frac{dl}{dt} &= s \frac{ds}{dt} \\
(18 \text{ ft})(-0.2 \text{ ft/s}) &= (7 \text{ ft}) \frac{ds}{dt} \\
\frac{ds}{dt} &= \frac{(18 \text{ ft})(-0.2 \text{ ft/s})}{(7 \text{ ft})}  \\
&= -\frac{18}{35} \text{ ft/s} \\
&\approx -0.5142 \text{ ft/s}
\end{align}

The boat is approach the dock at about $0.5142$ feet per second.

Comment: I tried the same thing, it didn't work, I tried both positive and negative and fraction form and decimal.

Comment: It sounds like you are entering your answer into some sort of computer program (e.g. WeBassign). In my experience as a TA, it pays to ask students if they are reading the directions carefully. Are you sure the answer is supposed to be given in ft/sec? Are you supposed to give an exact answer or a decimal (and if so, where do you round)? As a last resort, perhaps you might check to make sure that you don't have an accidental space before your answer when you are entering it.